# How to call a method in a jar file from a jersey web project?

Tags: java, maven, jar, jersey-2.0, web.xml

I've created a Maven Project (eng_comparison) in Eclipse IDE, with jersey-quickstart-webapp archetype.

**EngComparator.java**

> ```
>  package com.zoo.web.eng.eng_comparison;
>
>     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
>     import java.io.IOException;
>
>     import javax.ws.rs.GET;
>     import javax.ws.rs.Path;
>     import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
>     import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
>     import com.adv.zoo.web.model.auto.EngProvider;
>     import com.adv.zoo.web.model.auto.EngProviderImpl;
>
>
>     @Path("compare")
>     public class EngComparator {
>
>         public static String data = "safe";
>
>         @GET
>         @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
>       public String fetchContent() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Throwable {
>
>           EngProvider engProvider =   new EngProviderImpl();
>
>           String content = engProvider.getEng(data);
>
>           return content;
>
>       }
>     }
> ```

where EngProvider(interface) and EngProviderImpl(Class) are included in the project as a jar file.

**web.xml**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
>
>   <welcome-file-list>
>       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
>   </welcome-file-list>
>   <servlet>
>       <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
>       <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
>       <init-param>
>           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
>           <param-value>com.zoo.web.eng.eng_comparison</param-value>
>       </init-param>
>   </servlet>
>   <servlet-mapping>
>       <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
>       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
> </web-app>
> ```

While running this project on tomcat server (9.0), I'm the getting the following error.

[image: Internal Server Exception - Http Status 500]

NoClassDefFoundError : com/adv/zoo/web/model/auto/EngProvider
[image: Root Cause : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError]

ClassNotFoundException : com.adv.zoo.web.model.auto.EngProvider
[image: Root Cause : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException]

NOTE : I've added the EngProvider interface and EngProviderImpl class as a jar in the build path of the project, but still it's showing this error. I'm trying to call a method which is in the JAR file (added to build path)

**But when I run the project as a java application, it is working fine.**

My Project Structure :

[image: My Project Structure]

Comment: does your jar end up in WEB-INF/lib when creating a war?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, my JAR files are not getting into WEB-INF/lib folder when creating a war

Comment: that would explain why the class file is not there as the exception says.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks a lot. I've included the JARs in WEB-INF/lib, now its working for me.